# pymongo- How can I have distinct values for a field along with other query parameters

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo and want to have distinct values for a field such that I can also pass other query parameters. For example, I have entries like:

```
{
   id = "my_id1"
   tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3],
   category: "movie",
}
{
   id = "my_id2"
   tags: [tag3, tag6, tag9],
   category: "tv",
}
{
   id = "my_id3"
   tags: [tag2, tag6, tag8],
   category: "movie",
}
```

So I want to have all distinct tags under movie category. Can anyone please guide how can I achive this using pymongo. In mongo javascript shell, I issued db.mycoll.distinct('tags', {category: "movie"}) and it worked just fine. But when I do the same in pymongo it raises error. I guess it is not supported in pymongo. Any idea though how can such a task be achieved.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have to make the `distinct` call [on the cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct) returned from a `find` instead of on the collection:

```
tags = db.mycoll.find({"category": "movie"}).distinct("tags")
```

Answer (score 24):

pymongo (since v1.1.1) supports [`collection.distinct('key')`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct)

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is a filter parameter you can pass in distinct method as mentioned in the pymongo Doc,

[Pymongo Distinct](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=distinct#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct)

like this

```
distinct_tags = db.mycoll.distinct("tags",{"category": "movie"})
```