# flask pymongo distinct in collection does not work

Tags: mongodb, flask, distinct, pymongo

I'm trying to use the following line through flask:

***collection = 'mongo.db.vehicules.distinct("date_debut", {"modele":"Q5"})'***

When I don't insert the second arguments, the query works fine. 
With the second one, I have the following error:

*TypeError: distinct() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given*

The same query in Mongo shell works fine.

Anyone has faced the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for [pymongo distinct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879781/pymongo-how-can-i-have-distinct-values-for-a-field-along-with-other-query-param#12883331)

Comment: Thanks, it was that indeed.